# Does racket allow for function overloading?

Tags: racket

I am new to Lisp-scheme and fairly new to the functional paradigm as a whole, and am currently doing an assignment which requires me to overload a function with the same name, but different sets of parameters in `racket`. Below is an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
#lang racket

(define (put-ball-in-box two-by-fours nails ball)
  ... )

(define (put-ball-in-box box ball)
  ... )
```

These are not the actual functions, but close enough. As implied, both functions would put a ball in a box, but one would assemble the box from its components first, then call the other. Obviously, when I try the above in DrRacket or using the command line, I get a `module: duplicate definition for identifier ...` error.

Is there a way to achieve this in `racket`?

Maybe the answer is right in front of me, but I have spent the last two hours searching for this and couldn't find anything, so would appreciate any pointers.

Thank you.

Comment: It's possible to make your own version of `define` that allows that sort of thing. It's not a beginner project to make one though. For an example look at Formica:  https://github.com/samsergey/formica/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't in the usual sense of "writing another definition somewhere else."

It allows shadowing, which is defining a procedure with the same name as an imported procedure. Thus you can `(define + ...)` and your definition of `+` will hide the `+` from `racket/base`. If you want the original procedure, then you can do something like the following, where I define `+` to be either addition or string-appending.

```
 #lang racket/base
 (require (rename-in racket/base (+ base:+)))

 (define (+ . args)
   (if (andmap string? args)
       (apply string-append args)
       (apply base:+ args)))
```

Another thing you can do is use `racket/match` to have different behavior based on the shape of the argument.

```
#lang racket/base
(require racket/match)
(define (fib . arg)
  (match arg
   [(list n) (fib n 1 0)]
   [(list 1 a b) a]
   [(list 0 a b) b]
   [(list n a b) (fib (sub1 n) (+ a b) a)]))
```

This second example still doesn't quite do what you want since you have to go to the original definition point and modify the `match` clauses. But it might be sufficient for your purposes.

A more complicated example would be to use custom syntax to create a `define/overload` form. But I think you'll find the `racket/match` solution to be best.

Comment: Although I'd normally just write it out like you did, FWIW there are also some tiny sugar cubes like `define/match`, `match-lambda`, `match-lambda*`, etc. See https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/match.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fmatch..rkt%29._define%2Fmatch%29%29

Comment: Also note that there's [`case-lambda`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/lambda.html#%28form._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._case-lambda%29%29) which can be compiled more efficiently, but less versatile compared to `match`.

Answer (score 4):

You have the concept of default values as in JS and PHP:

```
(define (fib n (a 0) (b 1))
  (if (zero? n)
      a
      (fib (sub1 n) b (+ a b))))

(fib 10) ; ==> 55
```

Now if you had 5 optional parameters you need to order them and even pass some values just to be able to add a later one. To avoid that you can use keywords:

```
(define (test name #:nick [nick name] #:job [job "vacant"])
  (list name nick job))

(test "sylwester" #:job "programmer")
; ==> ("sylwester" "sylwester" "programmer")
```

Now Racket has classes. You can call a method like `(send object method args ...)`.

```
(define circle%
  (class object%
    (super-new)
    (init-field radius)
    (define/public (area)
      (* radius radius 3.1415))))

(define cube%
  (class object%
    (super-new)
    (init-field side)
    (define/public (area)
      (* side side))))


(define circle (new circle% [radius 7]))
(define cube (new cube% [side 7]))

(map
 (lambda (o) (send o area))
 (list circle cube))
; ==> (153.9335 49)
```

Notice that the two classes hasn't really commited to a joint interface with `area` so this is pure duck typing. Thus you can make a function that expects a class that implements a message and it doesn't need to worry about other aspects of the class at all.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tested both yours and law-of-lives' one, and both actually would have worked, so since I cannot accept both, as per [these guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255150/how-to-choose-between-multiple-correct-answers) I am going to upvote yours as it was also very helpful, and accept law-of-lives' one for posterity.

Comment: @claudiusbrout of curiosity I've added OO.