# What is Scheme's relationship with operators?

Tags: operator-overloading, scheme, racket

I am aware that Scheme has no operator precedence or operator associativity due to its use of s-expressions and the fact that operators are considered to be functions. However, I'm confused as to whether Scheme can do operator overloading. There isn't much information on the internet on that regard.

Comment: A lot of the OO systems available allow for overloading.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does racket allow for function overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48614078/does-racket-allow-for-function-overloading)

Comment: Scheme can do operator overloading, look at the *metaobject protocol* if you are interested.  I would say, the other languages where you heard about "overloading" were inspired from scheme.  Scheme goes to the essence of the concept, but this essence is not necessary to get a job.  One can live without operators in scheme.

Comment: There really are no "operators" in Scheme, and they are not "considered" to be functions – they *are*. There is no difference between `plus` and `+`, both are symbols that can be bound to any values. However, you can "do" overloading in the sense that you can implement the mechanism yourself.

Comment: In languages in which argument identifiers in program text are associated
with types, processors can do ahead-of-time selection between multiple
definitions for a given procedure identifier use. 
If this is what is meant by operator overloading,
it isn't possible in general in Scheme _qua_ Scheme, which has
"latent as opposed to manifest types" (R3RS, and all subsequent standards).